# Facebook chat XMPP authentication with Gloox?

Tags: c++, facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat, gloox

Well, I'm probably doing something silly, but I've been beating my head against the wall with this for the past few hours, and so far I have no idea what I've been doing wrong.

At the moment I'm trying to make this work with PLAIN SASL because it seems like Facebook actively makes OAuth2 a pain for non-Web apps, but it really makes no difference to me as long as I can get this to work somehow.

Current code:

```
_client = new Client(JID(username /* no @chat.facebook.com */), password);

_client->setServer("chat.facebook.com");
_client->setPort(5222);

_client->setSASLMechanisms(gloox::SaslMechPlain);
_client->setTls(gloox::TLSPolicy::TLSRequired);

_client->connect(false);
_client->login(); // not necessary?

QThread::sleep(10); // arbitrary sleep; should be sufficient

std::cout << _client->authed() << std::endl; // false
std::cout << _client->authError() << std::endl; // AuthErrorUndefined

_client->rosterManager()->fill();

// neither one has any effect
MessageSession(_client, JID("friend@chat.facebook.com")).send("balls");
MessageSession(_client, JID("friend")).send("balls");

std::cout << _client->rosterManager()->roster()->size() << std::endl; // 0
```

Edit: For that matter, I can't get Gloox working with Gmail either (haven't tried any other XMPP servers).

Answer (score 1):

1. Your JID is indeed `username@chat.facebook.com`, not only `username` - and it is very important to SASL authentication, it will not work with wrong JID.
2. Facebook chat supports SASL PLAIN authentication over SSL/TLS connection, as well as DIGEST-MD5
3. Google talk supports SASL PLAIN over TLS too
4. You can see supported SASL mechanisms in the first `<stream:features>...</stream:features>` packet from the server
5. It will be much better if your show error logs

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I ended up getting it working just by switching to Swiften, so it seems like either there's a bug in Gloox or I was doing something wrong (I'm guessing I needed to register event handlers, despite the docs' assertion otherwise). Roughly equivalent (working) Swiften code posted as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still not 100% sure what the problem with Gloox was, but the following roughly equivalent Swiften code works with no issues.

```
SimpleEventLoop* eventLoop = new SimpleEventLoop();
BoostNetworkFactories networkFactories(eventLoop);

_client = new Client
(
    username.append("@chat.facebook.com").toStdString(),
    password.toStdString(),
    &networkFactories
);
_client->setAlwaysTrustCertificates();

_client->onConnected.connect([&] () { signInStatus = SignInStatus::Success; });
_client->onDisconnected.connect([&] (const boost::optional<ClientError>& e) {
    signInStatus = SignInStatus::InvalidCredentials;
});

_client->connect();
std::thread([&] () { eventLoop->run(); }).detach();

while (signInStatus == SignInStatus::NotSignedIn)
{
    QThread::sleep(1);
}

if (signInStatus == SignInStatus::InvalidCredentials)
{
    return signInStatus;
}

_client->requestRoster();
QThread::sleep(5);
std::cout << _client->getRoster()->getItems()[0].getName() << std::endl;

Message::ref message(new Message());
message->setTo(_client->getRoster()->getItems()[0].getJID());
message->setFrom(JID());
message->setBody("balls");
_client->sendMessage(message);
```